# Showing an image on broswer using @ResponseBody in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, image

Hello i have this code to display an immage saved on my filesystem on broswer:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/prova/img/{id}", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody byte[] getImageWithMediaType(@PathVariable String id) throws IOException {
    String path = uploadFolderPath +"/"+ id;
    if(Files.exists(Paths.get(path)) && !Files.isDirectory(Paths.get(path))) {
        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
    }else {
        return null; //this is just for example it should never get here
    }
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot invoke "java.io.InputStream.read(byte[])" because "input" is null
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I am pretty sure that your code goes in the else clause and returns `null`. The code is correct, but your path of the image should be incorrect... My suggestion, take an image, put it somewhere where you can easily access it with the path (e.g `C:\img\test.jpg`), then check if the code above works. If it does, the problem is on your path...

Comment: it still not working, i think i'm missing something. can i try something else?
`

Comment: Inputstream In is null. What is the correct format for giving it the path of the image? i have the image on my desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code first tests that your input exists (as a `File`) and is not a directory, then you go ahead and try to read it *as a resource from the class path* using `getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)`. This is usually not what you want.

Try instead `InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);`.

Like this:

```
if (Files.exists(Paths.get(path)) && !Files.isDirectory(Paths.get(path))) {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
    return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
}
```

PS: If you are on Java 9 or later, you don't need the `IOUtils` dependency, simply use `readAllBytes`. And as you already use `Files` and `Path`, we can clean up the code a bit like this:

```
Path filePath = Paths.get(path);
if (Files.exists(filePath) && !Files.isDirectory(filePath)) {
    InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(filePath, StandardOpenOption.READ);
    return in.readAllBytes();
}
```